# If I roll 20 six sided dice, what is the chance of there not being a 1?

Tags: probability

Assume that the dice are fair. Wouldn't the answer be 5/6^20? I don't really know.

Comment: You're correct. They're presumably independent rolls, and the probability of each not being $1$ is $\frac{5}{6}$. Multiplying them since they are independent gives you $\big(\frac{5}{6}\big)^{20}$ as you suggest.

Comment: Yes, that is correct if you put parentheses around the $5/6$.  As written, it is only the $6$ that gets raised to the $20^{th}$ power.

Comment: @RossMillikan Good catch on the notational issue.

Comment: @CameronWilliams:  I rag on parentheses a lot.

Comment: That's correct. You can sharpen your intuition by writing down all the cases for two throws of a six sided die and counting the cases where you see no $1$.

Comment: OK. next, I might like an answer to what the probability is.

Comment: If you type it into a search box with the parentheses you will get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, provided that the die is fair and that the rolls are independent. This is because
$$
P(\text{No one's after 20 rolls)}=P(\text{No one on the first roll)} \times P(\text{No one on the second roll}) \times \dots \times P(\text{No one on the twentieth roll)} \, .
$$
And the probability of there not being a one on any single roll is $5/6$. Hence,
\begin{align}
P(\text{No one's after 20 rolls}) &= \underbrace{5/6 \times 5/6 \times 5/6 \times \dots \times 5/6}_{\text{20 terms}} \\
&= \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{20} \, .
\end{align}